# Application Insights - Investigate non-http Failures

Tags: c#, azure-application-insights

AI is well automated for HTTP but when you track operations in background workers, it's a bit more manual to set it up.

I can track exceptions like this...:

_telemetryClient.TrackException(e, ...

...and they show up as exceptions in AI, but the operation does not show up as failed.

I tried setting:

operation.Telemetry.Success = false;

... in the catch block.

This did not make a difference.
I'm hoping to see a list of failed operations.

[image: screen dump AI]

Comment: Please post some code in which we also can see where `operation` comes from

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft has a [page about this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/worker-service), there is a separate SDK for tracking Worker Services.

Alternatively, you could implement `OperationTelemetry` and write:

```
using (_telemetryClient.StartOperation<YourOperationTelemetry>("MyOperation"))
{
    //your code
}
```